# How do I get a the index of retrieved examples via faiss in huggingface datasets

Tags: huggingface

Here is example code:

```
ds = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
ds.add_faiss_index(column="embeddings", metric_type=faiss.METRIC_INNER_PRODUCT)
scores, nn = ds.get_nearest_examples("embeddings", question_emb, k=k)
```

Here we only get the nearest neighbours via `nn`, but how do I get the indices of those examples? Such that I can do `ds[index]`. I want to do this, as I want to fetch the adjacent entries too.